# Run Time Error 1004 on Do While Not ActiveCell.Offest(-1, RowCount).Value = ""

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I'm trying to write a macro. The macro is supposed to work by the user clicking on the first empty cell in column D. Then it should grab the tracking number to the left in column C. Navigate to the website. Return the delivered date into the first clicked on cell, then basically shift down one row and do the same thing without having to click again on the next row. Loop the process until you encounter the first emtpy cell in column C. This can't start at a particular cell every time because it's an on going spread sheet that's added too every week and this will start close the the bottom. For instance this week where I started was cell D2343. It's not finished code, but any suggestions would be helpful. I am fairly new to coding and extremely new to excel VBA so please bear with me. There's probably a better way to go about this than using activecell, but I'm not sure how. This

```
Public Sub Tracking()
Dim IE As Object
Dim ReturnValue As String
Dim ProUrl As String
Dim RowCount As Integer

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

RowCount = 0

'THIS LINE RETURN THE ERROR
Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset(-1, RowCount).Value = ""

ProUrl = "https://www.rrts.com/Tools/Tracking/Pages/MultipleResults.aspx?PROS=" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, RowCount).Value

With IE
   .Visible = False
   .Navigate ProUrl
    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With

ReturnValue = Trim(IE.document.getElementsByTagName("Span")(16).innerText)
ActiveCell.Offset(, RowCount).Value = ReturnValue

RowCount = RowCount + 1

Loop

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Stackoverflow has been a tremendous resource. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any merged cells or cells with an error like `#N/A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error may be in your `Offset` method. The first argument should be the row offset, and the second argument should be the column offset. It seems like you may have that backwards.

Try changing it to:

```
Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount, -1).Value = ""
```

Comment: Yes that worked. And you know, I had it that way yesterday, but I adjusted the code to do something else and changed that because I though it was wrong.

Comment: @sdrloveshim As you use VBA more, you will begin to learn what the sometimes cryptic error messages actually mean. Error 1004 pops up when you're trying to perform an action on an object that doesn't exist. In your case, when you try to offset a column before Column A, it obviously won't exist. You'll begin to catch these errors on your own in no time.